# Calculating acceleration from velocity as a function of distance

Tags: calculus, kinematics

This comes from USA Harvard-MIT Mathematics Tournament (I don't know from which year)

> A particle moves along the $x$-axis such that its velocity at the $x$-position is given by the formula $v(x) = 2 + \sin(x)$.
> What is its acceleration at $x = \pi/6$?
> (Answer is $2.2$)

How do I do this if I don't know velocity as a function of time?

Comment: Hint: apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for the one-dimensional motion that

$$v = \frac{d x}{d t} = 2 + \sin x$$

The acceleration is

$$a = \frac{d v}{d t} = \frac{d v}{d x} \frac{d x}{d t} = v \frac{d v}{d x}$$

by the chain rule. We have $\frac{d v}{d x} = \cos x$ so that

$$a = (2 + \sin x) \cos x$$

When $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$, $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Therefore, $a \left( x = \frac{\pi}{6} \right) = \boxed{\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{4}} \approx 2.165$.